# "Remote-Containers: Clone Repository in Container Volume" doesn't show branches

Tags: git, github

I cloned a GitHub public repo and it works fine.
But "git branch -a" doesn't show any of the remote branches.

Is that a limit of the about command ?
Is there a config option to change ?

Thx in advance,

Simone

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

Changed /config.

Old:
`fetch = +refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev`

New:
`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`